# ODBC driver for SQL server ignores connection timeout attributes

Tags: sql-server, linux, connection, timeout, odbc

I connect with sqlcmd from system 1 to system 2

```
./sqlcmd -S <system2_ip_address> -U myLogin -P myPassword -t 7
```

System 2 has a running MSSQL server. I can then read on system 1, from the databases existing on system 2.

```
1> select * from dbo.spt_monitor
2> go
```

If I cut off network connection between system 1 and system 2, and try to read again on system 1, it ignores the previously set SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT with the `-t 7` . If system 1 is a windows machine, the query always timeouts after 15 seconds. If system 1 is Unix, the query never times out and runs indefinitely. It only recognizes that connection to system 2 was lost when I recover the network connection.

How can I configure the timeout? Both -t ( SQL_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT) and -l (SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT) is completely ignored and if called from a windows machine, timeout is always 15 seconds, if called from a unix machine, timeout is always infinite.

Comment: Technically a connection timeout is not the same as a query timeout (which is after establishing a connection and waiting on a query to finish), so `-t` is not the timeout you want to be playing with anyway. From a Windows _client_ I was able to successfully use `-l` to both give up finding a non-existent server after 5 seconds, and to wait 45 seconds to do so. I don't have a Linux machine to use as a client to test the same, but it could simply be that `sqlcmd` there does not have all the same plumbing (working correctly).

Comment: 1. I establish the connection successfully 2. The connection is cut physically 3. The system detects the  connection lost because the query it starts never finishes. So if I can understand this correctly, I need to use `-t`, not `-l`. But I cannot influence the timeout. On windows it's always 15 sec, on unix it always runs indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to set the -Querytimeout=xxxx param?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: According to `Sqlcmd -?`, `-t` is query timeout